# Java Recursion Total Breakdown

Tags: java, recursion

```
   ArithmSumRec(n)
1. If n = 1
1.1 return 1
2. Else
2.1 return ArithmSumRec(n-1) + n
```

So for example we want to calculate when n = 5. it will look something like this.

```
Executing ArithmSumRec(5) ⇒ 5 calls to ArithmSumRec(...)
ArithmSumRec(5)
ArithmSumRec(4)
ArithmSumRec(3)
ArithmSumRec(2)
ArithmSumRec(1)
return 1 // base case
return 1 + 2 (= 3)
return 3 + 3 (= 6)
return 6 + 4 (= 10)
return 10 + 5 (= 15)
```

But my question is now, when the method returns the first time it's:

```
return  ArithmSumRec(5-1) + 5;
```

1. But what happens to that 5 that's outside the parentheses. Why doesn't the method return 9 (since (5-1)+5 = 9?) and instead it returns a 4? And where does that `+n` go?

And if there's a good thread already that I haven't found or website that thoroughly explains recursive methods, I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? Recursion is calling a method within a method until a 'stop' parameter is met

Comment: Maybe also post the ArithmSumRec() function in it's entirety.

Comment: Expressions are evaluated "inside to out," more or less. `ArithmSumRec(5-1) + 5` is exactly the same as `ArithmSumRec(4) + 5`. In fact, the bytecode that javac generates will be the same in both cases; javac will inline the constant expression `5-1` to just `4`.

Comment: @DarmaniLink: Yes i know what a recursive method is, the question is how does it work for that simple problem i posted. What happends when you make a recusive method to calculate the sum of all integers from 1-5.

Comment: @yshavit: But what happends to the +5? When the code is return (n-1)+n why does the method call it self only with the sum of n-1 and not the combined sum of (n-1)+n?

Comment: The `+5` is applied after the call to `ArithmSumRec(4)` completes. Is that not what you'd expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is order of operations.  A function call takes precedence over addition.  Thus, when you call

```
func(5-1) + 5
```

... the first operation is 5-1, giving 4.  Now the run-time system executes the call **func(4)**.  *After* this is done, it finally adds the 5.

Compare your situation with a different function call:

```
sqrt(5-1) + 5
```

This is equivalent to having the square root sign over "5-1" with a "+ 5" after all of that.  This simplifies to sqrt(4) + 5, or 7.  It does not evaluate to 9 (following your original statement as written), nor does it evaluate to 3 (from sqrt(5-1 + 5)).

Does that help?

Comment: Wow, yes. So because the function has precedence on (5-1)+5 this will continue untill the end and THEN, inline waiting to get operated are the +n numbers?

Just like (5*2)(5*1)+3, the 3 is waiting for the first two parentheses to be calculated?

Comment: Exactly!  In fact, that's how I teach it to my students.  Anything in parentheses comes first -- and a function call includes parentheses, so you have to finish *both* the evaluation (the **5-1** part) *and* the function call.  *Then* you can do that last **+5**

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Really appriciate it! Cheers

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to up-vote useful comments & answers (which I've already done) and select a favorite, so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive calls do not return anything until you stop the recursion. If there wouldn't be the

```
if (n==1) return 1;
```

the program would hang there.

But when you hit the return 1, then the whole calculation is clear and you can actually return a number:

```
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15
```